# How to debug Mate keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: logs, keyboard-shortcuts, mate-desktop

I want to assign two keyboard shortcuts to "media next".
An interesting idea I found was to create a custom shortcut that executes `xdotool key XF86AudioNext`, but that does absolutely nothing.
I changed it to `xdotool sleep 1 key a` to test whether there's an issue with holding other keys while xdotool presses the media next key. But that also did nothing.
Then I wanted to redirect the output, but both `xdotool key lalala &> /path/to/file.txt` and `xdotool key lalala > /path/to/file.txt 2> /path/to/file.txt` do not write into the file at all.
Something like `thisisnotacommand &> /path/to/file.txt` at least shows an error popup, but it does not write into the file either.

I was also not able to find any information online about where Mate stores its log files, which is really strange. Not even https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MATE#Troubleshooting includes that path.

What can I do to get any information about what went wrong when using a keyboard shortcut in Mate?

Comment: Workaround for almost all cases where this is needed: Open a tiny minimised console, execute the command in there and close it again: `uxterm -iconic -geometry 0x0+0+0 -e 'xdotool sleep 1 key a'` Apparently these shortcuts operate in a very different environment. One thing that I already figured out is that they don't have my aliases, which is somewhat understandable, I guess. But there must be more, because for example it doesn't work with `if` at all.